# How to resolve EOFError: EOF when reading a line?

Tags: python

Code:-

```
input_var=input("please enter the value")
print(input_var)
```

Error:-
Enter a value

> Runtime Exception
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "file.py", line 3, in 
>       n=input("Enter a value")
>   EOFError: EOF when reading a line

I have started learning Python and tried to run this simple input and print statement. But its giving me the above error. I have tried running it on a online python compiler and it runs fine but when running on a compiler provided in a learning portal I am getting the above error.

Comment: Which python version you are using?

Comment: The answer might have something to do with what "learning portal" you are using.

Comment: Yes probably @ScottHunter . Because it worked fine for pyhton3 and python2 both.

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried running it on a online python compiler and it runs fine but when running on a compiler provided in a learning portal I am getting the above error.

`input` simply reads one line from the "standard input" stream. If the learning portal removes access to it (either closes it or sets it as a non-readable stream) then `input` is going to immediately get an error when it tries to read from the stream.

It simply means you can't use stdin for anything on that platform, so no `input()`, no `sys.stdin.read()`, … (so the resolution is "don't do that", it's pretty specifically forbidden)

In this specific case, the learning platform provides a non-readable stream as stdin e.g. /dev/null:

```py
# test.py
input("test")
```

```sh
> python3 test.py </dev/null
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    input("test")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

if stdin were *closed*, you'd get a slightly different error:

```sh
> python3 test.py <&-
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    input("test")
RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stdin
```