# EOF when reading a line; Error occurs with input

Tags: python, input, error-handling, eof

So I am trying to make a simple car game with a command input, to ask the user what they want to do with the car. By the way I am using an online IDE because I am on a tdsb chromebook. However as I run it, I always get this EOF error. Can anyone help?

Here's my code:

```
print("Welcome to the car game")

run = True

while run:
   command = input("Enter Command: ")
   fuel = 5
   carstart = False
   carstop = True

   if command == "start" and carstop:
      print("Car has started")
      carstart = True

   elif command == "start" and carstart:
      print("Car is already started")
```

Here's the error:

```
Welcome to the car game
Enter Command: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    command = input("Enter Command: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: You are probably running Python 2, while this code is for Python 3. Find some place where you can run Python 3, that will make your life easier.

Comment: Your call to `input()` may be reading from an unreadable stream on your particular online platform, unfortunately. I had to Google what you meant by "tdsb" and Toronto District School Board came up as a result, so I guess that's in line with what you're describing.

Other people have asked and answered [this same question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55592550/how-to-resolve-eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line?rq=1). It's probably best to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: oh Thanks Thierry Lathuille, I never even noticed :)

Comment: But hold up I ran it on Python 3.6 and still got the same erroe. Thanks anyways