# Why am I receiving an EOF Error and how can I resolve it?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, input, eof

I am a beginner currently learning Python through "Python Crash Course: Third Edition" and I just started chapter 7, which involves inputs. Whenever I try to use an input, I will receive the EOF Error. For context, I am using Visual Studio Code.

This is what I enter into Visual Studio Code:

```
message = input("Tell me something, and I will repeat it back to you: ")
print(message)
```

This is what happens:

```
Tell me something and i will repeat it back to you: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\python_work\Chapter 7 python\parrot.py", line 1, in <module>
    message = input("Tell me something and i will repeat it back to you: ")
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: Check your line endings, it seems they are not recognized. You can also handle by your self, if no line follows, stop your procedure

Comment: How exactly are you running this code? It looks like you are using a function in VS Code which doesn't allow you to interact with your script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73993577/in-vs-code-when-running-a-python-program-via-the-debugger-with-internalconsole

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve EOFError: EOF when reading a line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55592550/how-to-resolve-eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line)

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURED IT OUT. It was because a long time ago I simplified the output in a launch.json file bye changing the console from "integratedTerminal" to "internalConsole", which doesnt allow user input.

Comment: Hi Andrew, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)